# Qlikview to display json data of mongo Db in Qlikview

Tags: mongodb, field, business-intelligence, dashboard, qlikview

I am new to qlikview and I have two tables now in the second table it is storing values in form of array .Now i want that array fields to be displayed as fields

Following are two tables which I am getting from my MongoDb

Calling_Circles:test_id--

```
XXXXXXXXX(its a mobile number)
```

calling_circles:text_contacts(here we have those number on whom the mobile number above has contacted and their characteristics)--

```
[{ "MSISDN" : "XXXXXX", "Date" : "2013-03-02", "Incoming_Count" : 0, "Outgoing_Count" : 11, "Total_Count" : 11, "is_XX" : "Y" }, { "MSISDN" : "XXXXXX", "Date" : "2013-03-02", "Incoming_Count" : 12, "Outgoing_Count" : 12, "Total_Count" : 24, "is_EE" : "Y" }, { "MSISDN" : "XXXXXXX""Date" : "2013-03-02", "Incoming_Count" : 0, "Outgoing_Count" : 19, "Total_Count" : 19, "is_EE" : "N" }, { "MSISDN" : "XXXX"Date" : "2013-03-02", "Incoming_Count" : 0, "Outgoing_Count" : 17, "Total_Count" : 17, "is_EE" : "N" }, { "MSISDN" : "XXXXXX", "Date" : "2013-03-02", "Incoming_Count" : 16, "Outgoing_Count" : 16, "Total_Count" : 32, "is_EE" : "Y" }, { "MSISDN" : "XXXXXXXX", "Date" : "2013-03-02", "Incoming_Count" : 15, "Outgoing_Count" : 15, "Total_Count" : 30, "is_EE" : "Y" }, { "MSISDN" : "YYYYYYY", "Date" : "2013-03-02", "Incoming_Count" : 14, "Outgoing_Count" : 14, "Total_Count" : 28, "is_EE" : "Y" }, { "MSISDN" : "YYYYYYYYYYY", "Date" : "2013-03-02", "Incoming_Count" : 0, "Outgoing_Count" : 10, "Total_Count" : 10, "is_EE" : "Y" }, { "MSISDN" : "XXXXXXX", "Date" : "2013-03-02", "Incoming_Count" : 11, "Outgoing_Count" : 11, "Total_Count" : 22, "is_EE" : "Y" }]
```

Now i want that the bar char should display attributes inside my  calling_circles:text_contacts against Calling_Circles:test_id

so once i click certain number in qlikview dashboard from 
Calling_Circles:test_id  the bar chart should display MSISDN it has called and the various attributes related to it

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand want you want/ need. Please describe both tables and add some example values. Then explain how these values should be displayed on the dashboard.

Comment: Can you also please add your qlikview load script. Or is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Yeah @Smartmera ,I am not getting the script to load .Actually i fetched the mongoDB data from qvsource and then i don't know how to fetch individual fields from BSON(JSON) data...............Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the data in to an appropriate data model in QlikView?

If not, I'd recommend to resolve JSON data with a JSON capable connector like QVSource ...

Regards
Stefan